# How can I check if values in one array are equal are equal without checking the same thing

Tags: java, logic

I have this array

```
Ball[] balls = new Ball[7]; // 7 just being an example
```

In my Ball class, I have getters and setters for x and y values.
I'm trying to compare the x and y values to make sure that they don't intersect.

My first thought was to make a loop looking like

```
for(Ball b1 : balls) {
    for(Ball b2 : balls) {
    if(b1.intersects(b1, b2)) {. . .} // I made intersects, not my issue 
    }
}
```

But this is no good, as it compares:

1. balls 0 to balls 0
2. balls 1 to balls 1
3. etc.

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(f.getContentPane().getWidth() + "\n" + f.getContentPane().getHeight());

       int radius = 10 + rand.nextInt(20);

       balls[i] = new Ball(360, radius,
               rand.nextInt(f.getContentPane().getWidth() - 4 * radius - 5) + radius + 5,
               rand.nextInt(f.getContentPane().getHeight() - 4 * radius - 5) + radius + 5
       );
   }
   for(Ball b1 : balls) {
       for (Ball b2 : balls) {
           while (b1.intersects(b1, b2)) {
               System.out.println("Ball started out inside of another, replacing now.");
               b1.setX(rand.nextInt(f.getContentPane().getWidth() - 2 * b1.getRadius() - 5) + b1.getRadius() + 5);
               b1.setY(rand.nextInt(f.getContentPane().getHeight() - 2 * b1.getRadius() - 5) + b1.getRadius() + 5);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

////////////// class change //////////////////

```
class Ball {
private int direction;
private int radius;
private int x,y;

Ball(int direction, int radius, int x, int y) {
    this.direction = direction;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// Getters + Setters here

boolean intersects(Ball b1, Ball b2) {
    double x = Math.pow((b2.getX() - b1.getX()), 2);    // Distance formula
    double y = Math.pow((b2.getY() - b1.getY()), 2);    // Distance formula
    double r = b1.getRadius() + b2.getRadius();

    //System.out.println(x + " + " + y + " <= " + r );
    return x + y <= r;
}
```

}

(Ignore that I didn't put my first hunk of code in a method and class, I've done that in my actual code.)

I, for whatever reason, can't think of a way to do this without a whole lot of if statements

(So I'm asking for the best way to do this)

Comment: Half of the question is pretty well-specced (how do I determine if `Ball`'s `intersect`), and half of the question is a little underspecified. What about a pathological case when all seven balls are precisely the same? What would you want to do then? Moving around balls in a random direction won't necessarily get you any closer to balls not intersecting either (or at the very least, could take a very very long time)…

Comment: Are you basically looking for a way to match up all the different pairs of `Ball`s?

Comment: Just check that `b1 != b2`.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that `intersects` is an instance method and accepts 2 arguments. Either make it static, or only pass the second ball.

Comment: Responding to dtanabe - I know how to see if they intersect. not my issue. May want to reread the question. If a ball is in another, in randomizes it's x and y until it's free. This way, 93 balls could be in the same spot, and it doesn't matter.

Comment: Responding to shmosel  - I know I can do that which a whole lot of ifs, but I want to know a more efficient way. Fixing the intersects() now, surprised I didn't see that. But that's not my issue.

(Thanks still)

Comment: How do you get a whole lot of ifs? It's just one.

Comment: If I have *n* number of balls, say 19. I need to see if 0 = 1, if 1 = 2, 0 = 2, 2 = 3, 1 = 3 (and so on)

Comment: I didn't say to check that `balls[1] != balls[2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to compare every distinct (i.e., no ball with itself) pair of `Ball`s, without comparing any pair more than once would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; ++i) {
    Ball b1 = balls[i];
    for (int j = i+1; j < balls.length; ++j) {
        Ball b2 = balls[j];
        if (b1.intersects(b1, b2)) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Detecting new collisions introduced in the process of resolving previous ones just means making multiple passes over `balls` until you no longer have any collisions.  A simple, perhaps naive, way of doing this would be something like this:

```
boolean foundCollision;
int numTries = 0;
int maxTries = 1000000;
do {
    foundCollision = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; ++i) {
        Ball b1 = balls[i];
        for (int j = i+1; j < balls.length; ++j) {
           Ball b2 = balls[j];
           if (b1.intersects(b1, b2)) {
               foundCollision = true;
               // resolve collision...
        }
    }
    ++numTries;
} while (foundCollision && numTries < maxTries);
if (numTries >= maxTries)
    System.err.println("Couldn't sort out balls after " + maxTries + "tries: what now?");
```

Comment: Wouldn't **i + 1** give me a *null pointer* if **i** is at its max?
This also wouldn't check if *ball 6* is intersecting with *ball 2*, so if 6 randomly is put onto 2, then I'm back to square 1.

Comment: You mean an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. But no, you won't get that because then `j < balls.length` would be false. And it will tell you if 2 intersects with 6, which *should* be the same as the inverse.